# Git complains about no such file or directory when using difftool

Tags: git, git-difftool

I configured git to use kdiff3 but it seems to give me the following error:

```
$ GIT_TRACE=1 git difftool
09:23:36.319531 git.c:419               trace: built-in: git difftool
09:23:36.321130 run-command.c:643       trace: run_command: GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF=git-difftool--helper GIT_PAGER= git diff
09:23:36.322094 git.c:419               trace: built-in: git diff
09:23:36.340596 run-command.c:643       trace: run_command: GIT_DIFF_PATH_COUNTER=1 GIT_DIFF_PATH_TOTAL=3 git-difftool--helper init.el /tmp/LqOdEz_init.el 397ab56b39cf979c392c807c714cade1b949d1dd 100644 init.el 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 100644
error: cannot run git-difftool--helper: No such file or directory
fatal: external diff died, stopping at init.el
```

My configuration is:

```
[diff]
    tool  = kdiff3
[difftool]
    prompt = false
[difftool "kdiff3"]
    cmd = kdiff3 "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
```

Any Idea what's going on? I'm on linux if that makes a difference and I'm using `git version 2.21.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to download [this script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/git-difftool--helper.sh) and put it in my path.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to define kdiff3 on your PATH variable